# Don't remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code which supplements a CSS-created navigation bar. Currently, the code removes the `active` class when a separate navigation button is pressed.

I'd like for the code to not remove the `active` class and allow more than one button to be active at a time. How can this be accomplished?

```
$(function(){
  $(".uibutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".uibutton").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});​
```

**Full code on jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KhyK7/

Comment: Its working as expected... What you are looking is not correct, since as per UI it looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function together with removing `removeClass("active")`:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KhyK7/1/)**

**Side note:** If you are using jQuery UI you could also consider the [checkbox buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code like so

```
$(function(){
  $(".uibutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);

    button.toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this way:-

```
$(function(){
  $(".uibutton").click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});​
```

As per UI, what you want is wrong.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/KhyK7/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can target the clicked event item and just add the class, easy...

```
$(function(){
  $(".uibutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".uibutton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: he says 'to not remove the active class'